# How to set the environment variable PYNGUIN_DANGER_AWARE for Pynguin?

Tags: python, unit-testing, environment-variables

I'm trying to use Pynguin to generate python unit tests for my project.

I get this message:

> "Environment variable 'PYNGUIN_DANGER_AWARE' not set.
> Aborting to avoid harming your system.
> Please refer to the documentation
> (https://pynguin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html)
> to see why this happens and what you must do to prevent it."

I know that I need to set `PYNGUIN_DANGER_AWARE` as an environment variable, but I'm not able to. I'm trying to set it in "edit configuration" in my Pycharm env, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `i'm trying to set it in "edit configuration" in my Pycharm env` so please show what you're doing so we can see what you might be doing wrong...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PyCharm, you can just set the value in the “Edit Configurations” by adding `PYNGUIN_DANGER_AWARE=` to the field “Environment variables” (see my screenshot):

[image: Screenshot of the Edit Configurations dialogue of PyCharm]

As mentioned in documentation the value of the variable does not matter, Pynguin only checks whether the variable is defined.

If you want to run Pynguin from the command line you can also set the variable there.  We, however, *do not recommend to set the variable as a system-wide variable*; Pynguin will execute the module under test during test generation, which can cause arbitrary harm to your system (depending on what the module under test's functionality is, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Outside of pyCharm you can use:

```
# Shell
export PYNGUIN_DANGER_AWARE=x # set for the current shell and child processes
PYNGUIN_DANGER_AWARE=x <followed by executing code>

# In Python at top of your script:
import os
os.environ[PYNGUIN_DANGER_AWARE]="ok"
```